# How to kill AsyncTask from inside asyncTask itself?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, kill

i have applied cancel method in the asyncTask to kill the asyncTask but it is still running
\
`cancel(true);
 asynchInterface.failed(null, index);`

Comment: it doesn't work that way. You have to implement cancelling logic in your asynctask yourself

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko can you give an example ?

Comment: depending on what you do in your task, you need to periodically check the `isCancelled()` method, and if it is `true`, then you have to stop whatever yu are doing  (return from `doInBackground()`)

Comment: Can i  completely kill the AsyncTask ?

Comment: no, you can't. It is not designed for that. Also *killing* something has high chance to produce unpredictable result

Comment: that means, asyncTask will still run in the background ? right ?, will it make performance issue ?

Comment: everything depends on what exactly you are doing and how exactly you will implement the cancel functionality